# Combining map + foldl?

Tags: haskell

I have an initial list. I want to create a new one such that each element of it is `max` of zero and the sum of the previous element + current one. The zeroth element is the same in both lists.

```
# preseudo code
lst = [.....]
newLst = []
newLst[0] = lst[0]
for i <- 1 to lst.length:
  newLst[i] = max(0, newLst[i - 1] + lst[i])
```

I know it has to do with `foldl`. However,  it also has to with `map` since both lists have the same size. But `map` doesn't have an accumulator. I can't figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3ascanl1):

```
scanl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
```

It returns all accumulated results, which is just what you want:

```
newList = scanl1 (\acc x -> max 0 $ acc + x) oldList
```

Example:

```
> scanl1 (\acc x -> max 0 $ acc + x) [1,2,3,4,-10,-20,1,2,-2,10]
[1,3,6,10,0,0,1,3,1,11]
```

Comment: can I it without scanl1 using recursion?

Comment: Of course you can do it with recursion.  Just look at how scanl1 is defined.

Comment: sorry, I can't find its definition. Do you mean this http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1 ? But that doesn't look like a definition.

Comment: @Alex There's usually a source link for every function in Hackage, here's the one to `scanl` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#scanl